# Idiomatic C++ for finding a range of equal length strings, given a vector of strings (ordered by length)

Tags: c++, string, stl

given a `std::vector< std::string >`, the vector is ordered by string length, how can I find a range of equal length strength?

I am looking forward an idiomatic solution in C++.

I have found this solution:

```
// any idea for a better name? (English is not my mother tongue)
bool less_length( const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs )
{
    return lhs.length() < rhs.length();
}

std::vector< std::string > words;
words.push_back("ape");
words.push_back("cat");
words.push_back("dog");
words.push_back("camel");
size_t length = 3;
// this will give a range from "ape" to "dog" (included):
std::equal_range( words.begin(), words.end(), std::string( length, 'a' ), less_length );
```

Is there a standard way of doing this (beautifully)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expect that you could write a comparator as follows:

```
struct LengthComparator {
    bool operator()(const std::string &lhs, std::string::size_type rhs) {
        return lhs.size() < rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(std::string::size_type lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
        return lhs < rhs.size();
    }
    bool operator()(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
        return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
    }
};
```

Then use it:

```
std::equal_range(words.begin(), words.end(), length, LengthComparator());
```

I expect the third overload of `operator()` is never used, because the information it provides is redundant. The range has to be pre-sorted, so there's no point the algorithm comparing two items from the range, it should be comparing items from the range against the target you supply. But the standard doesn't guarantee that. [Edit: and defining all three means you can use the same comparator class to put the vector in order in the first place, which might be convenient].

This works for me (gcc 4.3.4), and while I think this will work on your implementation too, I'm less sure that it is actually valid. It implements the comparisons that the description of `equal_range` says will be true of the result, and 25.3.3/1 doesn't require that the template parameter `T` must be exactly the type of the objects referred to by the iterators. But there might be some text I've missed which adds more restrictions, so I'd do more standards-trawling before using it in anything important.

Comment: Thank you, does "valid" means "C++ standard compliant"?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it loosely, but by "valid" I actually mean "guaranteed by the standard to do what you want". Strictly it means "guaranteed by the standard to have defined behavior", and code that doesn't do what you want is still "valid", but in this case I don't see a difference - the only way you'll get a wrong answer is if some technicality means the code I've written somehow violates the preconditions for `equal_range`.

Comment: It works with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (15.00.30729.01). I've done a very limited test.

Comment: @uvts_cvs: yeah, and for any given implementation of `equal_range`, you could probably just examine the implementations of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` to see that it will work. I'm just concerned that there's some general text somewhere about the whole bunch of algorithms that says, "the comparator must do X, Y and Z", even though most implementations won't rely on Z at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is definitely not unidiomatic, but having to construct a dummy string with the target length does not look very elegant and it isn't very readable either.

I'd perhaps write my own helper function (i.e. `string_length_range`), encapsulating a plain, simple loop through the string list. There is no need to use `std::` tools for everything.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I do not like very much the dummy string :-|

Comment: Depending on the size of the data and the required performance, it could be useful to use a binary search (since the strings are sorted by length).

Comment: I do agree, a binary search would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

`std::equal_range` does a binary search. Which means the `words` vector must be sorted, which in this case means that it must be non-decreasing in length.

I think your solution is a good one, definitely better than writing your own implementation of binary search which is notoriously error prone and hard to prove correct.

If doing a binary search was not your intent, then I agree with Alexander. Just a simple for loop through the words is the cleanest.

Comment: Yes, I need the binary search and the vector is sorted by string length (as the question title says).